# How do I find elements created on the same day

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table with an ID and a DATETIME which stores the creation date of the elements. I want to find elements created on the same day. To clarify for example let's say I have his table:

```
   ID       CREATED_DATE
|------|---------------------|
|  0   | 2013-02-03 20:49:06 |
|  1   | 2013-02-03 20:50:18 |
|  2   | 2013-02-04 07:13:03 |
|  3   | 2013-02-05 12:09:09 |
|  4   | 2013-02-05 23:37:32 |
| ...  | ...                 |
```

I want to find `(0, 1)` which created on `2013-02-03` and `(3, 4)` which are on `2013-02-05` and so on...
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DATE()` to get only the date from the datetime field.

```
SELECT  DATE(CREATED_DATE) DATE, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) IDList
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY DATE(CREATED_DATE)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9366e9/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*using DATE_FORMAT*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9366e9/3)

Or if you want to filter out only dates the have multiple ID created, add `HAVING` on the query,

```
SELECT  DATE(CREATED_DATE) DATE, GROUP_CONCAT(ID) IDList
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY DATE(CREATED_DATE)
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9366e9/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*using DATE_FORMAT*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9366e9/4)

Comment: *follow-up question: do you want to filter for specific dates?*

Comment: No. This is the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(CREATED_DATE) = '2013-02-03'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. 
Simple - date is like string, so:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CREATED_DATE = '2013-02-03'
```